# Angular Micro-frontend Issue: GET http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.js?v=3.3.4 net::ERR_FAILED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, micro-frontend, angular-module

Hi i have stuck angular microfrontend deploy issue. please provide any solution.

Thanks.

Access to script at 'http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.js?v=3.3.4' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.